# forcing a newline within a rotated title in longtable

Tags: line-breaking, longtable

I'm trying to build a table with a two row header. The text within the header is long so I'm rotating and hoping to split one of the longer headers like so. The current code produces the picture below. and the \newline command doesn't appear to work

\% of students in **\\** subject schools

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}    
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{longtable}{R{0.3in}|R{0.4in}R{0.3in}|R{0.4in}R{0.2in}R{0.3in}R{0.4in}|R{0.3in}R{0.2in}R{0.4in}R{0.3in}}
\caption{GCSE uptake} \\ 
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Population} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Subject reach} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Subject actual} \\\
 \begin{sideways}Region\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Schools\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Students\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Schools\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Students\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}per of all schools\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\% of all students\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Students\end{sideways} &  \begin{sideways}\% of students in \newline subject schools\end{sideways} &  \begin{sideways}\% of all students\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Avg Cohort\end{sideways} \\
 \hline
North West & 627 & 75103 & 405 & 62382 & 65 & 83.1 & 9873 & 13.1 & 15.8 & 24.4 \\ 
  East of England & 498 & 64314 & 323 & 52760 & 65 & 82.0 & 8211 & 12.8 & 15.6 & 25.4 \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `makecell` (to simplify the code for rotated cells) and `\pbox` (works like `\parbox`, except the specified width is a  *maximum* value):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\setlength{\rotheadsize}{1.1in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{longtable}{l|R{0.4in}R{0.3in}|R{0.4in}R{0.2in}R{0.3in}R{0.4in}|R{0.3in}R{0.2in}R{0.4in}R{0.3in}}
    \caption{GCSE uptake} \\
      \hline
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Population} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Subject reach} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Subject actual} \\%
    \thead[lb]{ Region} & \rothead{Schools} & \rothead{Students} & \rothead{Schools} & \rothead{Students} & \rothead{per of all schools} & 
    \rothead{\% of all students} & \rothead{Students} &\rothead{\smash{\pbox{\rotheadsize}{\setstretch{0.8}\raggedright \% of students \newline in subject schools }}}    
     & \rothead{\% of all students} & \rothead{Avg Cohort} \\
     \hline
    North West & 627 & 75103 & 405 & 62382 & 65 & 83.1 & 9873 & 13.1 & 15.8 & 24.4 \\
      East of England & 498 & 64314 & 323 & 52760 & 65 & 82.0 & 8211 & 12.8 & 15.6 & 25.4 \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just checking, you have to use rothead for this?

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary – it mainly simplifies the code, as it automatically turns by 90° counterclock wise by default. Also loading `makecell` can be useful for several other purposes.